# Не могу адекватно записать данные в базу данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3

Учусь работать с бд вообще и конкретно в тг ботах. Хотел просто, чтоб при вводе комманды '/start' выводился ID пользователя и записывалось это в бд. Столкнулся с проблемой в этом коде:

```
import telebot
import config
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread = False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш TELEGRAMM ID = " + str(user_id))
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO users(user_id) VALUES(?)", user_id)
    conn.commit()

bot.polling()
```

Ошибка:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO users(user_id) VALUES(?)", user_id)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Если изменю 13 строку на:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO users(user_id) VALUES(?)", str(user_id))
```

То ошибок нет, но оно записывает в бд все по одной цифре:

[image: База Данных]

(При создании бд выбирал тип INTEGER). Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) нужен для выполнения одного и того же запроса с разными наборами параметров (например, если вам нужно вставить несколько строк в таблицу). Вторым параметром должен быть список разных наборов параметров. Т.к вам нужно вставить одно число, то нужно использовать просто [execute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute), но вторым параметром должен передаваться кортеж (или список, или вообще любой итерируемый объект) параметров, даже если вам нужно передать только одно число (т.е. нужно передать кортеж или список с одним элементом):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_id) VALUES(?)", (user_id,))
# запятая после user_id нужна чтобы показать,
# что это именно кортеж с одним элементом, а не просто число в скобках
```

или

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_id) VALUES(?)", [user_id])
```

Когда вы преобразовываете число в строку, то метод `execute` воспринимает каждый символ строки как отдельный параметр, поэтому вставляется только первый символ числа.